# onsen notification to auto close after a set time

Tags: angularjs, cordova, notifications, onsen-ui, auto-close

Hi I am using Onsen as part of a AngularJS Phonegap/Cordova project.

I was wondering is it possible to to automatically close an Onsen notification after a set time. Also is it possible to not include the button?

My current notification is shown below:

```
var notifyAutoClose = function(title, message) {
        var options = {
            title: title,
            message: message,
            buttonLabel: '', //Don't show button if possible
            animation: 'default'
        };
        ons.notification.alert(options);            
    }
```

If it is not possible what would be the best non-bootstrap alternative when using AngularJS.

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom dialog using `ons-dialog` directive.

Check this code ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbBWPR)):

```
//HTML
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Dialog</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-list ng-controller="DialogController">
      <ons-list-item ng-click="show('customdialog.html','Dialog title', 'it will close after 2 seconds')" modifier="tappable">
         Custom dialog
      </ons-list-item>
   </ons-list>
</ons-page>

<ons-template id="customdialog.html">
   <ons-dialog var="dialog" modifier="android">
     <ons-toolbar modifier="android">
       <div class="center">{{title}}</div>
     </ons-toolbar>
     <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:50px">{{message}}</p>
  </ons-dialog> 
 </ons-template>

//JAVASCRIPT
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('DialogController', function($scope) {
   $scope.show = function(dlg,title,message) {
      $scope.title=title;
      $scope.message=message;
     ons.createDialog(dlg,{parentScope:$scope}).then(function(dialog) {
        dialog.show();
     });
     setTimeout(function(){dialog.hide()},2000)
   }
 });
```